# Oracle grouping/changing rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table named foo:

```
ID | KEY  | VAL
----------------
 1 | 47   | 97
 2 | 47   | 98
 3 | 47   | 99
 4 | 48   | 100
 5 | 48   | 101
 6 | 49   | 102
```

I want to run a select query and have the results show like this

```
UNIQUE_ID        | KEY  | ID1 | VAL1 | ID2 | VAL2 | ID3 | VAL3
--------------------------------------------------------------
47_1:97_2:98_3:99|  47  | 1   |  97  | 2   |  98  |  3  | 99
48_4:100_5:101   |  48  | 4   |  100 | 5   |  101 |     |  
49_6:102         |  49  | 6   |  102 |     |      |     |
```

So, basically all rows with the same KEY get collapsed into 1 row.  There can be anywhere from 1-3 rows per KEY value

Is there a way to do this in a sql query (without writing a stored procedure or scripts)?

If not, I could also work with the less desirable choice of

```
UNIQUE_ID        | KEY  | IDS   | VALS 
--------------------------------------------------------------
47_1:97_2:98_3:99|  47  | 1,2,3 | 97,98,99
48_4:100_5:101   |  48  | 4,5   | 100, 101 
49_6:102         |  49  | 6     | 102
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Unfortunately my real-world problem seems to be much more difficult than this example, and I'm having trouble getting either example to work :( My query is over 120 lines so it's not very easy to post. It kind of looks like:

```
with v_table as (select ...), 
  v_table2 as (select foo from v_table where...), 
  v_table3 as (select foo from v_table where ...),
  ...
  v_table23 as (select foo from v_table where ...)
  select distinct (...) as "UniqueID", myKey, myVal, otherCol1, ..., otherCol18 
  from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on...
  ... 
  inner join tbl15 on ...
```

If I try any of the methods below it seems that I cannot do group-bys correctly because of all the other data being returned.
Ex:

```
with v_table as (select ...), 
  v_table2 as (select foo from v_table where...), 
  v_table3 as (select foo from v_table where ...),
  ...
  v_table23 as (select foo from v_table where ...)
  select "Unique ID",
   myKey, max(decode(id_col,1,id_col)) as id_1, max(decode(id_col,1,myVal)) as val_1,
   max(decode(id_col,2,id_col)) as id_2,max(decode(id_col,2,myVal)) as val_2,
   max(decode(id_col,3,id_col)) as id_3,max(decode(id_col,3,myVal)) as val_3
  from (
    select distinct (...) as "UniqueID", myKey, row_number() over (partition by myKey order by id) as id_col, id, myVal, otherCol1, ..., otherCol18 
    from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on...
    ... 
    inner join tbl15 on ...
  ) group by myKey;
```

Gives me the error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

This is because I am selecting the UniqueID from the inner select.  I will need to do this as well as select other columns from the inner table.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: @user973479 - you need `"UniqueID"` in the `group by` clause of the outer query. Not sure why you want that alias in quotes, but it should still work. Also not sure about the `distinct` in your key generation, but assume you have a reason for that... `otherCol1` etc aren't being selected in the outer query so won't be visible, and if they are selected they will have to be in the `group by` too.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to fix up that error!  I'm still getting a bug where the wrong values are being populated in the val1-3 columns, but I'm currently looking into that to see what the issue is

Comment: Got it fixed and working as expected!  Thanks everybody for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
select key,
    max(decode(id_col,1,id_col)) as id_1,max(decode(id_col,1,val)) as val_1,
    max(decode(id_col,2,id_col)) as id_2,max(decode(id_col,2,val)) as val_2,
    max(decode(id_col,3,id_col)) as id_3,max(decode(id_col,3,val)) as val_3
from (
        select key, row_number() over (partition by key order by id) as id_col,id,val
        from your_table
    )
group by key
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look ath [this article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515) about *Listagg* function, this will help you getting the comma separated results, it works only in the 11g version.

Answer (score 2):

As @O.D. suggests, you can generate the less desirable version with [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions089.htm#sthref1220), for example (using a CTE to generate your sample data):

```
with foo as (
select 1 as id, 47 as key, 97 as val from dual
union select 2,47,98 from dual
union select 3,47,99 from dual
union select 4,48,100 from dual
union select 5,48,101 from dual
union select 6,49,102 from dual
)
select key ||'_'|| listagg(id ||':' ||val, '_')
        within group (order by id) as unique_id,
    key,
    listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids,
    listagg(val, ',') within group (order by id) as vals
from foo
group by key
order by key;

UNIQUE_ID          KEY IDS                  VALS
----------------- ---- -------------------- --------------------
47_1:97_2:98_3:99   47 1,2,3                97,98,99
48_4:100_5:101      48 4,5                  100,101
49_6:102            49 6                    102
```

With a bit more manipulation you can get your preferred results:

```
with foo as (
select 1 as id, 47 as key, 97 as val from dual
union select 2,47,98 from dual
union select 3,47,99 from dual
union select 4,48,100 from dual
union select 5,48,101 from dual
union select 6,49,102 from dual
)
select unique_id, key,
    max(id1) as id1, max(val1) as val1,
    max(id2) as id2, max(val2) as val2,
    max(id3) as id3, max(val3) as val3
from (
    select unique_id,key,
        case when r = 1 then id end as id1, case when r = 1 then val end as val1,
        case when r = 2 then id end as id2, case when r = 2 then val end as val2,
        case when r = 3 then id end as id3, case when r = 3 then val end as val3
    from (
        select key ||'_'|| listagg(id ||':' ||val, '_')
                within group (order by id) over (partition by key) as unique_id,
            key, id, val,
            row_number() over (partition by key order by id) as r
        from foo
    )
)
group by unique_id, key
order by key;

UNIQUE_ID          KEY  ID1 VAL1  ID2 VAL2  ID3 VAL3
----------------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
47_1:97_2:98_3:99   47    1   97    2   98    3   99
48_4:100_5:101      48    4  100    5  101
49_6:102            49    6  102
```

Can't help feeling there ought to be a simpler way though...